# text_changed event not working

Tags: c#

```
private void txtName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
    {
        dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["someValue"].Value = txtName.Text;
    }
}
```

When the text is changed in the text box it should be displayed in the datagrid view,if i select cell already having data then it works fine but if i select a new row(empty row) the text does not appear in the datagridview 
allow user to add row is set to true for the datagrid view.

Comment: @BugFinder yes i have,I found that i does add the data to datagrid view but a new row should be created as soon as i enter the value into the empty cell so that user can add more rows but its new row does not appear

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your textbox AutopostBack property is set to 'true'..otherwise textchanged event will not fire

Comment: OP is using Windows Forms DataGridView so do u think AutoPostBack property will work here

Comment: here he has not mentioned that he is using windows forms for datagrid and if he is using windows form then autopostback will not work. it will work for web forms